# (PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR: type "hstore" does not exist) in rails production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, digital-ocean

I have a element with type hstore, during the migration for schema it does not work even though the database is enabled with hstore extension.I get a `(PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist)` error during migration. This work perfectly in local. How to make it effect across all schema?

Answer (score 2):

That extension is most likely located in schema outside of `search_path` for the user that is used in query that gave you error.
You can fix it either by recreating extension in public schema:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore WITH SCHEMA public;
```

Note that it is possible to change default setting and not have `public` in `search_path`.

Or adding to search_path schema that has hstore located at:

```
ALTER ROLE your_role_name
SET search_path = public, your_role_name, some_schema_with_hstore_extension;
```

This requires new connection to take effect. You can also use `SET search_path ...` in session to have immediate effect for that session only. I do not remember at the moment if permissions are required for `your_role_name` to schema `some_schema_with_hstore_extension` and hstore objects within it; most likely it is required, but might already be granted.

Answer (score 1):

To create extension in your database, you have to explicitly connect to that database. So, if your database is my_app_development, you have to do :

```
sudo -u postgres psql my_app_development
create extension hstore;
```

Also, you do not tell which rails version you're on. If you're not on rails-4, you will have to use the [postgres hstore gem](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore).

Comment: `ERROR:  extension "hstore" already exists` when i ran the above command... :(

Comment: i'm using rails 5 and the gem is not working ,. ` undefined method `alias_method_chain' for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:Class (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
SELECT public.hstore_to_json(hstore_col) 
FROM ...;
```